# Invalid Option Error in Grunt

Tags: gruntjs

Here's my grunt file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
'use strict';

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
        files: {
            'public/static/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css': 'public/static/scss/<%= pkg.name %>.scss'
        }
    },

    uglify: {
        options: {
            report: 'min'
        },
        files: {
            'public/static/js/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js': 'public/static/js/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
        },
    }
}

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'uglify']);
};
```

But when compiling I get the error:

```
OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: --report
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are missing a closing bracket to close your `dist` task. 
Should be:

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      style: 'compressed'
    },
    files: {
      'public/static/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css': 'public/static/scss/<%= pkg.name %>.scss'
    }
  }
},
```

Whereas yours is:

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      style: 'compressed'
    },
    files: {
      'public/static/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css': 'public/static/scss/<%= pkg.name %>.scss'
    }

},
```

You then will have a trailing `}` at the end of your file before `});`, remove this and should all run smoothly.

Comment: Thanks but that gives me: >> SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: Have revised my answer above. You now have a single closing `}` at the end of your file to remove.